# How to edit a FF add on?

Tags: firefox

Theres a firefox add on i would like to edit. I never made a plugin before and have looked at one before. Is there a tutorial or something on how to -edit- one? I do not know how to test the add on and ext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much difference between "editing" and what the add-on developers do.

You can simply locate the add-on in the /extensions/{add-on's ID} folder and make your changes to it (if parts of its code are in a JAR, you'll need a program that can edit files in zip archives, like Total Commander on Windows; in this case you also need to edit the code while Firefox is closed). Restart Firefox to see the changes.

This way is OK for few simple changes, but pretty inconvenient otherwise, so you'll want to [set up the development environment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Setting_up_extension_development_environment) if you're doing non-trivial changes. It's nothing scary if you have some technical background.